# Page Not Found needs some love

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found

What's wrong in the picture?

> [image]

1. "contact us" link is still a `mailto:` while it should be the same link as the one in footer.
2. "Browse popular tags" text has couple of stalker characters. (template again? :))

Both are cross site on all [404 pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/dummy) around the network.

Comment: Sam changed his user name to waffles to embrace the existing Meta meme, not create it. The 404 page theme is still appropriate.

Comment: It's a conspiracy!

Comment: @Cody I see... fair enough, will remove this one. :)

Comment: I wonder why the waffles picture is a link...

Comment: @Antony guess kind of legal notice. :)

Comment: the trailing ") is actually another template bug... I'll ask around what to do with the contact us link

Comment: @m0sa Ah, $YetAnother$ #SubstitutionBug#.")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything pointed out in this question is fixed as of build 2013.8.6.1313 (meta) / 2013.8.6.920 (sites), except for the [waffles](http://gizmodo.com/5700592/typewriter-waffle-maker-serves-up-belgian-qwertys) - they are still delicious!

Comment: May I ask why the waffles picture is a link?

Comment: Nice, thanks a waffles! Is this possible to make the drop down in [contact page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) auto select the "Other" reason when coming from the 404 page? (possible by checking the referrer, even client side :))